# HTTP/2 protocol not recognised

Tags: ssl, http2, pagespeed-insights

The latest update of PSI is reporting that all our site pages are using HTTP1/1 when in the fact they are running under HTTP/2. Confirmed this with the domain host and two separate tests.

Comment: What’s the domain? And when you open the “Use HTTP/2” section is it your primary domain it’s complaining about? Or other resources loaded by your site?

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for coming back to me. The domain name is https://rivergippingtrust.org.uk and it is the primary domain. I've been in touch with Siteground (domain registrant) and they confirm the protocol is http/2 and I've used a couple of checks I found on the net to prove that.

Answer (score 0):

Yup can confirm you're definitely using HTTP/2.

This looks to be a bug with PageSpeed Insights and [looks like you're not the only one experiencing it](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/7326#issuecomment-791387597).

If you run Lighthouse locally (either through Chrome, or even with the command line), or through [Web Page Test](https://www.webpagetest.org/) then it doesn't complain about missing HTTP/2 but it does for [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and [web.dev/measure](https://web.dev/measure/).

Suggest you follow that GitHub issue I linked above, and maybe add a comment with your own site.

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for looking. I did as you suggested and ran Lighthouse locally and the HTTP/1.1 error wasn't there. (Unfortunately it threw up several more errors in my website that I didn't know about from PSI, but that's a whole new world!). I think I'll wait for better brains than mine to resolve PSI and sort out the other errors using Lighthouse. At least that gave me an overall performance score of 95 for the home page against 86 from PSI.

Comment: PSI only looks at Lighthouse performance audits. https://web.dev/measure does the full Lighthouse Audits. But advantages to both: https://twitter.com/tunetheweb/status/1368207773549404160?s=21. And yes the score depends on settings used (inc CPU and bandwidth available).

Comment: Thanks Barry. I don't have a Twitter account so can't follow that but the link to dev.web seems easier to use than the one I found - https://www.webpagetest.org/lighthouse - and gives more help. It seems in my case that the bandwidth (and time of day) is important as I'm getting mobile results wavering between 78 and 95 for the Performance measure. I need to improve the Accessibility score. Trouble is I'm using the Divi theme for links to icons for Twitter and Facebook in the bottom bar but I can't add an 'alt' attribute to either using Divi. I'll have to try using a graphics module to fix it.